# Range using character variable

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have following variables

```
Dim A,i
A="C"
i=200
```

I want to construct `Range("C200")` using variable `A` and `i` from above, how to do this?

Comment: What do You mean by "constructing Range"? If I get you right, Range(C+Cstr(i)) should do it...

Comment: I meant I want to implement Range("C200")  using A and i variable

Comment: doesn't `Range(A+Cstr(i))` do the trick?

Comment: Yes it did Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

`Range(A+Cstr(i))`

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
 Range(str & "200")
```